# importing file into R program?

Tags: r

I just starting using the R program and was having some trouble figuring out what is wrong with my program. I imported a file into my R program and I keep getting the error 'object 'corn' not found' and 'object 'cotton' not found' when trying to ask for the mean and standard deviation for 'corn' and 'cotton'. The following is the beginning of my program and the .txt file I imported:

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))

# data
detach(data)
data<-read.table("D:/stalkeyedflies.txt", header=T)
attach(data)

data
names(data)
summary(data)

# mean and standard deviation of corn
mean(corn)
sd(corn)

# mean and standard deviation of cotton
mean(cotton)
sd(cotton)
```

---

This is what the .txt file looks like:

```
Treatment   eye.span
corn    2.15
corn    2.14
corn    2.13
cotton  2.12
cotton  2.07
cotton  2.01
```

Thank You So Much in Advance!!

Answer (score 4):

You should subset by column. For example:

```
mean(subset(dat,Treatment=='corn')$eye)
[1] 2.14
> mean(subset(dat,Treatment=='cotton')$eye)
[1] 2.066667
```

Or better here you should use `tapply` to apply the mean by group of treatment:

```
tapply(dat$eye.span,dat$Treatment,mean)
    corn   cotton 
2.140000 2.066667
```

Here dat is :

```
dat <- read.table(text='Treatment   eye.span
corn    2.15
corn    2.14
corn    2.13
cotton  2.12
cotton  2.07
cotton  2.01',header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
data<-read.table("stalkeyedflies.txt", header=T)
data
corn<-data[data$Treatment=="corn",]
# get the subset of corn
mean(corn[,"eye.span"])
# calculate the mean of corn

cotton<-data[data$Treatment=="cotton",]
# get the subset of cotton
sd(cotton[,"eye.span"])
# calculate the sd of cotton
```